# Showing MySQLi results from 3 months ago until today

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli

I have looked for help on this question around searches and attempted to edit my code based upon those questions but with no luck so I am hoping somebody might be able to help here.

I have a database with a bunch of transactions by a datetime stamp `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

I am trying to pull results from 3 months ago, up to today although my code doesn't seem to be functioning correctly? No matter how much I change my date within the database, nothing happens?

I've tried `>` and attempted to change around the `AND` and `OR` statements and have have fiddled with the way I mark up the variable eg: `'$variable' {$variable} ``$variable``` again with no luck...

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$months3 = strtotime('-3 months', strtotime($today));
$months_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , $months3 );

$user_email = $_SESSION['email_address'];

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `ap_payment_logs` WHERE 'txn_date' BETWEEN '{$months_ago}' AND '{$today}' AND user_id = '$user_id' OR payer_email = '$user_email' ORDER BY 'txn_date' DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Just think about it as selecting date > three months ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about performance aspect of this, but you can do something like this in mysql:

```
WHERE txn_date >  NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

if your table also has records that are in the future, you should add the condition that the 'txn_date' should be smaller than NOW()

that would then change your sql query to:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `ap_payment_logs` WHERE 'txn_date' > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND (user_id = '$user_id' OR payer_email = '$user_email') ORDER BY 'txn_date' DESC LIMIT 10";
```

hope that helps

Comment: Worked perfectly - although I did notice that I needed to add the `user_id = '$user_id' OR payer_email = '$user_email'` within brackets `( )` as the system was mistaking it as where date is after 3 months ago OR payer email is email. But I didn't realize you could do it automatically within the MySQL so thanks for teaching me an easier way to go about it!